# laravel php artisan migrate Error (timeout)

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I am using Laravel 5.6

when I use the command 'php artisan migrate' I get this error (after a minute) :

"Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = MYDATABASE and table_name = migrations)"

I have set up the correct database configuration in .env and config/database.php

I checked that my db connection works :
if(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName())
{
echo "Yes! successfully connected to the DB: " . DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
}

And it works.

if i run the query directly in mysql, it will not work because of the lack of quotes.
if instead I run this in mysql it will work:

select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'MYDATABASE' and table_name = 'migrations'

the issue in php artisan seem to be : "Operation timed out" 
(not the usual "File not found" when i tried to look for an answer here.

How to solve the php artisan migrate issue ???
thank you!

---

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and it turned out my host was incorrect.

In my `.env` file I set `DB_HOST` to the correct value and it all worked like a charm.

Comment: I do have the same problem when using valet in Mac can u please help me on this.